# Function parameters in Ajax callbacks

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript and back-end programming and in one of the frameworks based off of it ([Sencha Touch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sencha_Touch)).

I am making an AJAX call to the server and then executing the success or the failure callback (right?) functions. However, I am noticing that it is the programmer's choice to write or not to write all the parameters. For example, at one place, I saw `success: function(conn, response, options, eOpts)` and at the other, `success: function(response)`.

Why is there such a difference? Is such variability in parameters a JavaScript thing?

Answer (score 0):

> Why is there such a difference? Is such variability in parameters a JavaScript thing?

In JavaScript you usually just define the formal parameters that you are going to use. It is not an error if the caller passes more or fewer arguments than there are formal parameters.

For example:

```
function foo(bar, baz) {
   console.log('bar', bar);
   console.log('baz', baz);
   console.log('all arguments', arguments);
}

foo(); // ok
foo(1); // ok
foo(1, 2); // ok
foo(1, 2, 3); // ok
```

The function can always<sup>1</sup> access all passed arguments via the special `arguments` variable.

A more practical example:

[`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) passes *three* arguments to the callback:

- The current element
- Its index in the array
- The array itself

However, most of the time you will find that people only declare the first parameter, because that's all they are going to use:

```
var arr = [1,2,3].map(function(value) { return value + 1; }));
```

---

<sub>1: Unless you have an array function, where `arguments` is resolved lexically.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

In JS, you can call a function with any number of arguments. They'll all get received by the function. On the function end, you can optionally name them. It's not like other languages where you "must" pass the same number of arguments as defined in the function.

Comment: Does the order of the parameters not matter either? Like when I say success(response), I am calling my first parameter "response" and when I say success: function(conn, response, options, eOpts), my second parameter is response. How does the function know what to capture in what variable?

Comment: @ion20 Order matters. Usually people order arguments with required first, optional later because you can opt to not name the later arguments. In your example though, I believe those are success handlers of different operations, hence `response` is not in the same order.